# on c3.js X axis transform thick to yearly -> monthly->daily

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, c3.js

I would like to see the X axis on each calendar year.
I want to see it on the X axis by week, month and day.

The example code is below.

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        json: [{
            date: '2014-01-01',
            upload: 200,
            download: 200,
            total: 400
        }, {
            date: '2014-04-02',
            upload: 100,
            download: 300,
            total: 400
        }, {
            date: '2014-06-03',
            upload: 300,
            download: 200,
            total: 500
        }, {
            date: '2014-10-04',
            upload: 400,
            download: 100,
            total: 500
        }],
        keys: {
            x: 'date',
            value: ['upload', 'download']
        }
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: function (x) {
                    return x.getFullYear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

In this code, the X axis is bound to be fixed by each year, but if you modify the " getFullYear " function, you do not know how to change it. I'd like to change weekly, monthly, and daily. Help me.

Comment: You want month and day appear with the year like '2014-10-04'? Could you explain it better?